# Can Cassandra hold an empty list?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I want to create a Cassandra collection with some `list<int>` field and insert an empty list;

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    scores list<int>,
);

INSERT INTO test (name, scores)  VALUES ('John', []);
```

However, this returns `null`

```
SELECT * FROM test;


 name |scores
------+------------
 John | null
```

Does Cassandra not differentiate between `null` and empty list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always the recommendation goes with Cassandra don't insert NULL or try to insert EMPTY values. Its just saving yourselves from Tombstones, storage, I/O bandwidth.

The reason why Cassandra doesn't differentiate NULL Vs empty is because the way deletes are handled. There is no read before deleting any record in Cassandra. So it just marks as a tombstone and moves ahead.

So actually you get penalized to initialize the list as empty (essentially creating tombstone).